# I cannot get ChoiceField dropdown to display in my form

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, django-templates

I have been trying to get choicefield to work as part of a modelform however I have had no success. So I have attempted a very simple form to see if I could display a drop down of some sort however I still can't! 
I would be very grateful for anyone that could help me get even a simple choicefield form working so I can build from there.

**forms.py**

```
class NewArticleForm(forms.Form): 
    c =[("1", "Option 1"), ("2", "Option 2")]
    choices = forms.ChoiceField(choices=c, label="Choices")
```

**views.py**

```
def post_new(request):
    form = NewArticleForm()
    return render(request, 'fitness/name.html', {'form': form})
```

**name.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


{% endblock %}
```

**html output**

```
    <form method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="H2VgcltevhDfUMbM90W9j8i7sitdVDIR6ywei1MMzn9FcRZrjq1FVUXB2b88eXbU">
        <p><label for="id_choices">Choices:</label> <select name="choices" id="id_choices">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>

  <option value="2">Option 2</option>

</select></p>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: if you inspect the html. is the form empty?

Comment: Sorry I’m new to this , how should I check this ?

Comment: right click on the submit button, click on inspect and check what's above.

Comment: see edits in original question

Comment: yeah so the select is right there. if you can't see it it's probably some css that's to blame

Comment: I've removed css and it now works thank you very much!